# How does file_entity_file_download work with file_file_download?

Tags: files

I've recently upgraded my file_entity module and now have access woes on managed private files.

`file_file_download()` is granting permissions, as it should, by looking up whether the user has access to the node that owns the file. This part works.

However, `file_entity_file_download` is returning a deny (`-1` in place of headers array), but the implementation of this completely ignores the node access records - which is odd - instead just going on whether a user has view private files permission.

Some users get access to some files - there is no concept of view all private files on my site.

Can anyone shed any light?

Comment: Pretty sure you're referring to [this bug](https://www.drupal.org/node/2351691)

Comment: @Clive you're my hero :-) Nightmare resolved.